# Show that the following linear transformations are isometric.

Tags: functional-analysis, isometry

> Let $X$ be a Banach space. Let $L\subset X$ is a closed linear manifold. $P:X\rightarrow X/L$ is the quotient map. Show that the following linear transformations are isometric.
>
> 1. $\gamma:(X/L)^*\rightarrow L^a$ where $\gamma(\phi)=\phi\circ P$.
> 2. $\beta: X^*/L^a\rightarrow L^*$ where $\beta(\phi+L^a)=\phi|_L$
>
> (Here $L^a=\{\phi \in X^*: \phi(x)=0 \;\text{for all} \;x\in L\}$)

So if we think about the first one, we need to prove that $||\gamma(\phi(x))||=||\phi(x)||$(Am I correct?)

So, $||\gamma(\phi(x))||=\sup_{||x+L||=1}|\phi(x+L)|$ and $||\phi(x)||=\sup_{||x||=1}|\phi(x)|$. Moreover, $||x+L||=\inf_{y\in L}||x+y||$. But now I don't see a way to compare $||\gamma(\phi(x))||$ and $||\phi(x)||$. Is my approach correct? Can somebody please help me to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

1. We have that
   $$\Vert \gamma(\phi) \Vert =\sup_{\Vert x+L\Vert=1}\vert\phi(x+L)\vert \leq \sup_{\Vert x+L\Vert=1}\Vert\phi \Vert \Vert x+L\Vert = \Vert\phi\Vert.$$
   Now you just need to show that "$\geq$" holds.
2. Due to the Hahn-Banach-theorem $\beta$ is surjective. For all $\phi \in X^*$ we have
   $$\Vert \phi  + L^a \Vert= \inf_{\psi \in L^a} \Vert \phi  + \psi \Vert \geq \inf_{\psi \in L^a} \Vert (\phi  + \psi)|_L \Vert = \Vert \phi |_L \Vert = \Vert \beta(\phi  + L^a )\Vert. $$
   Using Hahn-Banach-theorem there exist an extension $\Phi \in X^*$ of $\phi |_L$ with $\Vert \Phi \Vert = \Vert \phi|_L \Vert$. Hence 
   $$\Vert \phi  + L^a  \Vert \leq \Vert \phi  + \underbrace{(\Phi - \phi )}_{\in L^a}\Vert = \Vert \Phi \Vert = \Vert \phi |_L \Vert = \Vert \beta(\phi  + L^a )\Vert.$$
   Hence $\beta$ is isometric.

I hope that it helps you :)

Comment: For 1., I understand how you get $||\gamma||=1$, but where did we prove that $||\phi||=1$?

Comment: "Now you just need to find an $\phi \in (X/L)^*$ with $\Vert \gamma(\phi) \Vert =  \Vert\phi\Vert$ to conclude that $\Vert \gamma \Vert = 1$." This is a small exercise I left :)

Comment: But how does showing $||\gamma||=1$ implies it is an isometric? Don't we have to show that $||\gamma||=||\phi||$?I'm confused.

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad. Ofc You have to show the it her inequality.